# How to define a range of values while preparing data for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am learning basic machine learning classification problem where I am training a model for a problem where if `age` is more than `15`, output will be `1` and if `age` is less than `15`, output will be `0`. I have prepared a csv file which can be downloaded from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FeDfhH2-xrqzFydVI_qGW_RkqlhGal6p/view?usp=sharing

Below is the code I am using:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
data.head()

X = data[['Age']]
Y = data["Output"]

train = data[:(int((len(data) * 0.8)))]
test = data[(int((len(data) * 0.8))):]

clf = LogisticRegression()
train_x = np.array(train[['Age']])
train_y = np.array(train["Output"])
clf.fit(train_x, train_y)

test_x = np.array(test[['Age']])
test_y = np.array(test["Output"])

test_x2 = np.array([[16]])
Y_pred = clf.predict(test_x2)
print(Y_pred)
```

This is working fine. In `text_x2`, if I give value 16, it shows output as 1 which is correct. If I give test value as 12, it shows output as 0 which is correct. If I give test value as 2, it still shows 0 which is correct, but I haven't trained the model for age as `2`, so why does it work?

I also want to know how can we define range in the data. For ex, if age is 0-15yrs, then output should be 1. If age is 16-30, output should be 2. if age is 31-45, output should be 3.

Answer (score 1):

During training, your model has to learn the optimum values of βo (bias) and β (weight parameter for age feature). You can use this line of code to get the values of βo and β that the model has learnt.

```
print(np.hstack((clf.intercept_[:,None], clf.coef_)))
```

The parameters that your model has learnt works well for the given input of "2", you can try it yourself by putting the parameter and input values in logistic regression function. Moreover, ML models have the ability to interpolate and extrapolate and that means you don't have to
train your model on every possible input.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what bias and weight parameter are and whats their role in training please?

Comment: Check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHwlB_j7Hkc&ab_channel=ArtificialIntelligence-AllinOne